# Finding a Series with Properties

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find a sequence $S(n)$ that has the following properties:

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty} S(n) = 0$
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{S(n)}{n}$ is divergent.

I've tried different kinds of sequences such as $2^{-n}$, $0.5^n$ and a few others but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Isn't $2^{-n}=(0.5)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**

For later questions, when testing such sequences the well known general Harmonic Series, the $p$-series, and the $\ln$-series might prove helpful.

Note that

$$S(n)=\frac{1}{\ln n}$$ if $n \neq 1$ and $S(n)=1$ if $n=1$.

suffices, as seem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#ln-series).

since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\ln n}=0$$ while by integral test $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^p}$$ diverges if $p \le 1$ but converges if $p>1$.

Comment: If n = 1, ln(n) = 0 which would lead to dividing by zero for the first value in the series.

Comment: @Asea Noted and corrected.

Comment: I figured out a function from your note and edit, thanks!